# Keep some of Spring Boot MVC default configurations while implementing WebMvcConfigurer

Tags: java, spring

I want to implement custom `addCorsMappings` and `addResourceHandlers` , bit also to keep other Spring boot MVC configurations (e.g. `getMessageCodesResolver`)

According to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html) doc:

> If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features and you want to add
>   additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view
>   controllers, and other features), you can add your own @Configuration
>   class of type WebMvcConfigurer but without @EnableWebMvc. If you wish
>   to provide custom instances of RequestMappingHandlerMapping,
>   RequestMappingHandlerAdapter, or ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver,
>   you can declare a WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter instance to provide such
>   components.

But implementing `WebMvcConfigurer` requires implementing all other methods which I don't want.

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeCwheoqc24) video tutorial no issue is raised though. How can I only implement some methods and not all of them?

Note: `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated.

Comment: No it doesn't (at least nog if you are using Spring Boot 2 which requires Spring Framework 5 which has that interface with all default methods. Default methods are a new feature of java 8 and Spring uses that.

Comment: The spring boot version I'm using is '2.0.4.RELEASE' and the spring web mvc version I'm using is 2.5.2. I'm using Java 1.8. Everything is supposed to be in place, right?

Comment: Why on earth are you using Spring 2.5.2? That isn't just old that is ancient and probably won't even work. Jus use the regular version that comes with Spring Boot (which should be 5.0.8).

Comment: I used spring initializer to create the project. The most recent version is 2.1.0 M1. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: 2.1.0 is not a final version yet that still is under development (M1 = Milestone, which is basically a pre-release/test version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 introduced [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html). Which basically means a default implementation for a method but then defined on an interface.

Spring 5, which has Java 8 as a baseline, took advantage of this and for several interfaces, [`WebMvcConfigurer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.java) is one of them, they used this. The `WebMvcConfigurer` has all its methods default implemented.

This means that instead of extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` you can just implement `WebMvcConfigurer`. Because of the default methods the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated as that isn't needed anymore.

So no as of Java 8 and Spring 5 you don't need to implement all methods of an interface anymore. Ofcourse the interface would need to provide `default` methods.